# Torified IMAP and SMTP

Tags: torsocks, email

I’m a newcomer to Tor, so please take that into account. :)

I wonder if it is useful to torify (actually, torsocks) programs such as msmtp and offlineimap, which I use to receive and send emails (I use mutt as MUA). The email account is a regular one (no .onion kind of thing), hosted by a big evil company I have no control over (say, for the sake of the argument, a gmail account).

As far as I understand it, the interest lies in preventing people (say, the sysadmin of the wifi network or my Internet service provider) from knowing I’m downloading and uploading emails. But maybe I get something wrong…

Useful? Harmful? Thanks in advance for your explanations.

Comment: You may want to start your own Hidden Mail server. I've some blog posts about configuring a hidden mail service, connecting to the hidden mail service through pc (thunderbird, which is a cross platform mail client from Mozilla) and through Android (K-9, open source Android Mail client). The links are here: 1) https://mstajbakhsh.ir/configuring-a-hidden-email-server/          2) https://mstajbakhsh.ir/connecting-to-hidden-mail-server/          3) https://mstajbakhsh.ir/my-contribution-in-k9-android-mail-client/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you want to have your smtp and imap connections over Tor is just the same as with using TorBrowser, but may vary from user to user. I'd say you **prevent your local network and ISP to know** what you are doing; you **protect your local surrounding** that way too, if you will.

And you get **location-privacy regarding your remote email provider**. That doesn't have to know where you are connecting from at all. Why tell them when you are home or using the phone or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your local ISP or sysadmin won't know what is done from *this particular connection*, but if the email provider authenicates you - he knows that it's you who downloading the stuff